# Removing a Single Sent Remote Notification From Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I was wondering how to remove a remote notification after is has been sent on the receivers end, if the message has been deleted by the sender. Example, if user A sends a message to user B and user A deletes the message before user B sees it on their device.

IMessage does it when you receive a text (iPhone) but open it on another device (mac pro) the iMessage push notification will be removed on the first device (iPhone).

Also, Ive noticed gmail does it, when you receive a push notification of a new email (on iPhone) but you delete it on the gmail web page (mac pro) the push notification will go away on the lock screen or notification center of my device (iPhone).

Any help will be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove remote notification from Notification Center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231120/remove-remote-notification-from-notification-center)

Answer (score 3):

I guess gmail does it by using the background mode for remote notifications, and then responding to these notifications by issuing a local notification.
You can remove local notifications, but not remote notifications.