# Programmatically delete Remote Notifications from Notification Centre

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, ios10

How can we pragmatically remove any pending remote notifications sent for my app from notification centre. I want to clear them up on app launch.

I have tried with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` API but its not helping.

PS: This question is specific to iOS 10 and old threads are not duplicates for this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove single remote notification from Notification Center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925854/remove-single-remote-notification-from-notification-center)

Comment: @SargisGevorgyan This cannot be marked as duplicate as the shared link talks about non-iOS 10 solution. iOS 10 handles it in a different way!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally...

This one works like charm!

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all notifications from notification centre by using these simple lines of code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

use wherever you want. From my side I have used when user pressed logout. 
You can use in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method to clear notifications after app opens

Comment: I had tried this already and its not helping. I am talking about remote notifications here. May be I should edit my question.

Comment: the line [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
will clear push notifications as well

Comment: Thats not true!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should do it by using the background mode for remote notifications, and then responding to these notifications by issuing a local notifications.
You can remove local notifications, but not remote notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please point me to documentation which confirms that remote notifications cannot be removed from Notification Centre? I am finding multiple versions online.

Comment: Can't find the official doc on this yet, but you can have a look here for now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231120/remove-remote-notification-from-notification-center

Comment: Its possible. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reseting the application badge number also remove all the notifications (local & remote) from the notification center.

**Objective C**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

**Swift**

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset the badge count WITHOUT deleting all notifications?

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be achieved by using removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:) method available in UserNotifications.framework.

For a detailed tutorial, please follow this

https://medium.com/@sebastianosiski/implementing-removable-remote-notifications-on-ios-a17d74832bde